# How to terminate speech recognition when user stop speaking with swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make user speak and get what user says right. I read like 20 different articles about speech recognition and almost all is same. It keeps listening to user for like 1 minute or more. I want it to stop recognation when user stop speaking. I want to catch  a word/few words that user says. Is there something limiting the time that user speak?

My code block :

```
func recordAndRecognizeSpeech(){

    if recognitionTask != nil {
        recognitionTask?.cancel()
        recognitionTask = nil
    }

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .measurement, options: .duckOthers)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
    } catch {
        print("audioSession properties weren't set because of an error.")
    }

    recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

    let node = audioEngine.inputNode
    guard let request = recognitionRequest else {
        fatalError("Unable to create an SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest object")
    }

    //request.shouldReportPartialResults = true

   // Setting requiresOnDeviceRecognition to false would use the Apple Cloud for speech recognition.
   if speechRecognizer?.supportsOnDeviceRecognition ?? false{
       request.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true
   }

    guard let myRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer() else {
        // A recognizer is not supported for the current locale
        return
    }

    if !myRecognizer.isAvailable {
        // A recognizer is not available now
        return
    }

    recognitionTask = speechRecognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request, resultHandler: { result, error in

        if let result = result {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                  let bestString = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                  print(bestString)

            }
        } else if let error = error {
            print(error)
            self.audioEngine.stop()
            node.removeTap(onBus: 0)

            self.recognitionRequest = nil
            self.recognitionTask = nil

            self.speakButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    })

    let recordingFormat = node.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
    node.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat){buffer,_ in
        self.recognitionRequest!.append(buffer)
    }

    audioEngine.prepare()
    do {
        try audioEngine.start()
    } catch {
        return print(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the power of the sound input, and if it reach a minimum value, start a timer (like 3 seconds), and stop after the timer fire.

```
var recorder: AVAudioRecorder?
recorder.updateMeters()
let dB = recorder.averagePower(forChannel: 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but can i make it without using AVAudioRecord?